# File system virtualization - is this doable with C#/.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, filesystems, virtualization

I want to write a Windows desktop app with C# that virtualizes a certain file system folder basically so that the app stores files in a folder and makes the file system see the files and sub folders in this folder as if they were files/sub folders in another folder somewhere else (the virtualized folder).

Can this be done with C#? 
And can it be done without file access performance penalties?

I know some apps written in C++ that do this but I want to use C# (because more modern and I'm more familiar with it). Perhaps there are even some libs available for this? I only came across **sharpfilesystem** but - without having looked too deep into it yet - I'm not sure it can do what I'm looking for. I'm also not sure if file system virtualization is the right word used for what I want to do so please correct me if this is something else (symlinks, aliases are related).

Comment: Wouldn't this need a custom filesystem driver?

Comment: My approach would be an emulated HDD which actually writes into a file on the disk or somewhere, but as @JamesHughes suggested it would need a system driver and i haven't heard of one which is only C#. EDIT: I just found https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/hardware/drivers/wdf/getting-started-with-umdf-version-2 maybe this is helping.

Answer (score 1):

The technology you are after is called Shell namespace extension (SNE). Unfortunately, there is [no (supported) way of creating a managed SNE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd758089(v=vs.85).aspx):

> Microsoft recommends against writing managed in-process extensions to Windows Explorer or Windows Internet Explorer and does not consider them a supported scenario.

For your particular scenario, [NTFS junction points](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/205524) might be good enough though.

Comment: Junction points aren't really practical for what i want to do. However if you're interested, I found exactly what I was looking for: https://github.com/TanninOne/usvfs This is a C++ dll but I think this can be used in C#.